# PHP html_get_contents weird characters

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get some data from the JSON API url: "http://turtlepool.space:8117/live_stats".
On the website it looks normal but as soon as I'm using HTML_GET_CONTENTS its shwoing me all these weird charcters:

```
š[‹$G’…ÿŠÈçD¸›ßóqØ]æabÑ²ƒüª.¦»JT—F¡ÿ¾ŸEFfFu÷Ã¶@T™G„¹Ûåœcõç©¿<¯§_N—?O¿¾¼¾}>]þyýétqü;ŸÆÓZOý·oœ.Áƒe~î§Ëé/¿7ŸÇwêëø½¾ÎÓ_çÛïï”w·þð4¾{­Ï¿ÌoÝœø÷þfkÌñî¿?ýòáÏ?ŸOêç¯õmþïÓóxùýt‰zÇšót1ßÛ3Ç|zæÞ·ß^ß>Îí—«ížŸôÐV¯Ößÿãî÷§úúËÔ0°òùOíå#÷ÿôß?ýã¤;ùõíÃéâuS/Ïõíé…‡ÿù×ùôïùúyûåôoû½ýÞsí§§çëŸæóÛO^çç/ÇñHÏ/\°=A·²ï¤}|éÿúééÓÜÝüíó‡žžŸžùÏçÚ>Nž°êÇÏó|ú} ½MîŸçÛï/¯ÿÒl%{ aº]ŸJrÄå 'Ÿßê§_1›] Q=¾N‹)Ñ½NÃË©¦‘¶Â’Ú¼S¬í^|o=•h\é’­-fšjût]æðž'†ÚKYÞt·È3iÖPþyÂ­†þÏÓÇúùíozâÿzùí§§ëNl6JÑ[¶xhmžF%GŸ[.¹uïL^®—Ù\ÏÉ˜Ôr÷£³;ß¥Fb)œsôàæÊ½ºì.g_‰©„xá&”Â²ÙŽìDÈœÕSe~àœ²ÚÌ6Ö‘§­¦ÊÙ„Š-Ä¡Eé©Mi.-NâðÉÄàÜp³µV
```

Etc.

Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks, Kevin :)

Comment: html_get_contents ? there's a `file_get_contents` function in PHP, but no html_get_contents as far as I know.

Comment: can we see some code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use CURL and json_decode:

```
$curl = curl_init('http://turtlepool.space/live_stats'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PORT, 8117); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 8117); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
$result = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($result, TRUE);
```

That's probably because of encoding

Comment: Thanks man! This fixes it :)